# How can i hide android keyboard on navigation toggle click

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I want to hide the keyboard on my android application when I click on the navigation button. I have searched for a solution but none worked for me.

**NavigationDrawerActivity**

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity

implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_doctor) {

        }  else if (id == R.id.nav_about_us) {

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {

        }
            else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**My application looks like this** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hGrP.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this,                 
    mDrawerLayout,        
    R.drawable.ic_drawer,  
    R.string.drawer_open,  
    R.string.drawer_close) {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
             View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
             if (view != null) {  
                 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
             }
    }
});
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: In which of the files should I add this, please?

Comment: see the edited answer, put this code after the definition of the DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 (if the input method has been shown in the window, the hidden, conversely display)**       `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);`
**Method 2 (the view to accept the view of soft keyboard input, SHOW_FORCED said forced display)**
 `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.showSoftInput(view,InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);`    `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);//Forced to hide the keyboard` **To obtain input method open state**
`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

boolean isOpen=imm.isActive();`

Answer (score 0):

problem is occur you  are using edit text when app run keyboard automatically open , to stop it you can add  to your AndroidManifest.xml: Activity's name where edit text is used like you use edittext in mainActivity then you write this :- android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" for other activity you can call it like above. and also add hide keyboard code after press backbutton your code is :

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);      
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();    
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```